# How to make user profile image reflect a transparent background?

Tags: media, users

I made a site with Drupal 7.26. Added on the Advanced Forums module with some other things.

Everything works fine except the user profile image is displayed with a white box/background instead of being transparent in the forums and user profile when clicking on the user name. I'm using a png image that has a transparent background.

Here's a cropped screenshot of how the picture is being displayed in the forums.
[image]

As you can see there is a white box/background instead of it being transparent. The strange thing is that when I hover over the image with my mouse the white box/background disappears and the image displays as it should.

Here's a cropped screenshot of what it looks like when the cursor is hovered over the image.
[image]

That is how I would like the profile pictures to be displayed in the forums should a picture have a transparent background.

Does anyone know of a setting or something on how to get this done?

I'd really really appreciate any help with this as I'm pretty clueless.

Thanks in advance for any replies

Barrels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image background is transparent when you hover over it, then the picture has transparency, and must be a .png or .gif file.

Therefore the white background must be down to CSS

In Chrome or Firefox, right click on the image and select "Inspect Element". Find the CSS controlling the div or img, and change the CSS from

```
.picture {
   background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

to

```
.picture {
   background:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. That was perfect. This is my first post so I don't have the required reputation to vote your comment up. Thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)